# "The function runtime is unable to start"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-functions-runtime

I know it probably has something to do with a misconfiguration, but unfortunately the most info I get is

> The function runtime is unable to start.  Session Id:
>   b939c608ae424150878a55eeac6e7d36 Timestamp: 2018-10-04T18:05:22.023Z

My function looks like

```
    [FunctionName("DoJob")]
    public static async Task DoJobAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("job-queue", Connection = "MyServiceBusConnection")] string json, ILogger log)
    {

       … 

    }
```

and my my local.settings.json is like

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
      "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
      "MyServiceBusConnection": "[my service bus connection string]"
    }
}
```

The function app builds locally and publishes, but as soon as I navigate to it in the portal I get the above error.

I am using .NET Standard (V2) and the latest version 1.0.22.

Also, if I try to test in the portal I get 500 Internal Server Error but nothing shows up in Log Streaming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Functions Portal error - The function runtime is unable to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213015/azure-functions-portal-error-the-function-runtime-is-unable-to-start)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without any further info, I assume you may forget to add `MyServiceBusConnection` in Application settings on Azure portal, which will cause same error you have seen.

If it's not the case, you could go to `https://<functionappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and navigate to `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host` to see function runtime logs.

Comment: This information is a little out of date. The console is not in the bottom tab of the azure function management window. That URL seems to no longer work

Comment: That URL works for me and I'm using the latest version of Azure Functions

Answer (score 3):

The URL does not work for me, but there is an easy way to get the same results. Go to `Development Tools` then `Advanced Tools (Kudu)`. From the `Debug console` menu, choose `CMD`. Navigate `LogFiles`, then `Application`, then `Functions`, then `Host`. Then examine the log files.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exception in the application Insight.

Open the application Insight from the 'Function Apps' page in the Azure portal:

[image]

Inside the Insight open the Failures:

[image]

You can see there all the exceptions, and drill inside each one of them.